# How to configure meetme.conf Asterisk for conference call?

Tags: config, asterisk

I want to make a call one number from multiple number. It's like conference call. what must i do with my meetme.conf?

Comment: if configuration just sets room number and other.
Maybe, I still confuse with my softphone. Is there some adding configuration at client or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change something in extension.conf file below is small example of it.

exten => [YOUR_NUMBER],1,Answer
exten => [YOUR_NUMBER],2,Meetme(1234786,sdm)

please replce with your number and then try to dial those number from multiple location you all are in one single conference room.

Comment: it can connect but audio can't hear anymore. do you know?

Comment: I use AsteriskWin32. I read some reference, Meetme not supported.
is it still an issue? or already solved?

Comment: What if I use extensions.lua ? i.e. I am not using extensions.conf , then what should I do for this ?